# Linking Waits to a process/statement

Tags: performance, sql-server-2016, waits

I'm starting to take on more of a DBA role and trying to get tooled up with scripts and knowledge to help with this.

I have been trying the sp_blizt procs in a dev environment. A key area I'm trying to focus on is understanding Waits.

My question is when you see a list of Waits how do you relate them back to a proc/query that is causing them?

For eg. When I see asyn_network_io, how can I show which client app is causing this and what is it running at the time to cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is when you see a list of Waits how do you relate them back to a proc/query that is causing them?

You can't, generally speaking. You mention in a comment on another answer that your monitoring tool shows you a jump in wait stats. If your monitoring tool can't correlate resource spikes to what was running at the time, you have a bad monitoring tool.

Tools that  make that easy include

- [Sentry One Performance Advisor](https://www.sentryone.com/products/sentryone-platform/sql-sentry/sql-server-performance-monitoring)
- [Quest Spotlight](https://www.quest.com/products/spotlight-on-sql-server-enterprise/)

If you're already using one of those and having a hard time, you should schedule a call with a vendor representative to walk you through the product.

You also can't use most scripts to figure out what happened later. You have to catch things while they're happening. Some easy ways to do that (for free):

- [Logging Activity Using sp_WhoIsActive – Take 2](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/07/logging-activity-using-sp_whoisactive-take-2/)
- [First Responder Kit Power BI Dashboard](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/first-responder-kit-power-bi-dashboard/)

If you're on SQL Server 2017 or higher, and you have [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017) enabled, it will [track aggregated waits stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

It's up to you to keep track of these things, though.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using sp_blitz , info at Brent's site itself is very helpful and should get you going https://www.brentozar.com/sql/wait-stats/

In addition to above there is a wealthy of information by Paul at https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/ which should get you going to see top waits

Waits is good point to start troubleshooting but that does not mean you have performance problems as the data being gathered matters since the more granular that wait stats data is i mean aggregate much better

E.g

> . When I see asyn_network_io, how can I show which client app is
>   causing this and what is it running at the time to cause this?

Yes, you can use the one at Brent site i think called sp_bltzwho or sp_whoisactive written by Adam Mechanic and get more info on host name plus other related data on current running queries causing those wait types or queries waiting on

Comment: They are some very interesting reads those links. sp_blitzwho and sp_whoisactive seem very useful. However, this leads to another question. I have some monitor software and every now and then I get a huge jump in Waits happening, these don't occur at any specific time and only last for a short amount of time let say 30 seconds. How can i do something like sp_whoisactive after it has happened?

Answer (score 0):

Just a few notes on async_network_io wait.  There are several scenarios that I see these commonly pop up:

- Queries returning large datasets
- Client side resource constraints/slow client applications
- MS Access applications
- Network issues (TCP retransmissions, high packet latency)

Queries returning really large datasets can result in this showing up - especially on slower networks.

A client that is 100% cpu constrained or experiencing some other performance degradation can cause this to surface on the database.  Be sure to look at if your client calling SQL is having issues - problem might not be in SQL Server, but on the client.

MS Access applications tend to surface this wait event.  It's been a while since I've played with Access, but if I remember correctly some of their controls that paginate data initiate a query, but don't consume all the results immediately.  Instead it will consume the results as you page through.

Network latency, errors (i.e. retransmits) will cause this to surface.  If you query data over a VPN this is another common source of this wait.

I hate to use this to shill our wares, but I think it deserves mention since you are discussing two different approaches above and we tie the two into one tool.

Using sp_whoisactive gives you a current point in time of who is actively running a query.  Tools like sentryone and spotlight collect wait stats historically for queries.  We combined the two approaches into one.  We collect query level wait stats historically, but sample session activity (similar to sp_whoisactive) and store it historically so you can see the sessions tied to the query that experienced async_network_io_wait and see all the details (i.e. program name, user, etc) of the sessions involved on a second by second basis. We have a completely free version of [SQLGrease](https://www.sqlgrease.com) you can use to troubleshoot your problem without being spammed or marketed to.